# replacing もの (noun) with もん (noun)

Tags: slang

There are many usages of もん, but the one I am interested in is using もん to replace もの (tangible noun). For example:

`安いもん` (lit translation: cheap stuff) can be used to replace `安いもの`

The question is, can it be used to modify a sentence into a noun in a complex sentence? For example:

`このナイフは安いもんが結構鋭いわよ` (Notice that the もん modifies the sentence into a noun in a complex sentence)

If I recall correctly, this is grammatically wrong because もん can only replace もの if and only if it is at the end of the sentence. For example, the sentence `このナイフは安いもん` is grammatically correct, but not `このナイフは安いもんが結構鋭いわよ`.

I realize that one will still definitely understand the meaning of the sentence perfectly well, but is this structure actually ever used?

Comment: `I realize that one will still definitely understand the meaning of the sentence perfectly well` -- ううん、わかりません.. What do you mean to say by that sentence?

Comment: @Chocolate あれ、間違ったのでしょうか。I'd thought the sentence would unarguably (literally) translate to "This knife is cheap stuff, but it is pretty sharp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that もの(物) "thing" "stuff" can be contracted to もん, eg 安い[物]{もの}, [良]{い}い[物]{もの}, 欲しい[物]{もの} → 安いもん, いいもん, 欲しいもん etc. in colloquial speech, especially in Kansai.

> このナイフは安いもん

It makes sense, but grammatically speaking it's not a *full* sentence; to say "This knife is cheap stuff", you need a copula だ/です at the end.

> このナイフは安い物です。
>   このナイフは安いもんだ。

... but [安物]{やすもの} would be more common/natural in this case:

> このナイフは安物です。
>   このナイフは安もんだ。

---

> "This knife is cheap stuff, **but** it is pretty sharp"
>   このナイフは安いもん**が**結構鋭いわよ。

The conjunctive particle が ("but") should be attached to the terminal form (終止形) of a verb, adjective, etc., like this:

> このナイフは安物**です**が、結構鋭いですよ。
>   このナイフは安物/安もん**だ**が、結構鋭い。

Or more colloquially:

> このナイフ、安もんだけど、結構鋭いわよ。